# How to assign ad content to stacklayout using Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mobile, admob

I want to assign a banner content into stacklayout. In my MainPage.xaml I create a new stacklayout with x:Name="Advertising".

```
<StackLayout x:Name="Advertising">

    </StackLayout>
```

Now I want to move the content from my banner directly into stacklayout. My c# code in my MainPage.xaml.cs is:

```
AdmobControl admobControl = new AdmobControl()
        {
            AdUnitId = AppConstants.BannerId
        };
        

        Content = new StackLayout()
        {
            Children = { admobControl }
        };
```

How can I move the content `Children = { admobControl }` into my new stacklayout with x:Name="Advertising" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add it to the existing `StackLayout`

```
Advertising.Children.Add(admobControl);
```